# Missing or invalid dependancy on sample Play project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am doing the sample Play project in Scala from https://www.playframework.com/. I have followed all the steps in the video. However, when I run `sbt compile` I get this error:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Logging.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Logging.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.
[error] ScalaWeb/app/views/index.scala.html:5: value addPerson is not a member of controllers.ReverseApplication
[error]     <form action="@routes.Application.addPerson()" method="post">
[error]                                       ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The error appears in this file:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    <form action="@routes.Application.addPerson()" method="post">
        <input name="name" type="text">
        <button>Add Person</button>
    </form>

}
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
name := """ScalaWeb"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"
```

`application.scala` looks like this:

```
package controllers

import models.{DB, Person}
import play.api._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  val personForm: Form[Person] = Form {
    mapping (
      "name" -> text
    )(Person.apply)(Person.unapply)
  }

  def addPerson = Action { implicit request =>
    val person = personForm.bindFromRequest.get
    DB.save(person)
    Redirect(routes.Application.index)
  }

}
```

`plugins.sbt` is this:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
```

What could cause this?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `Logging.class`. Can you add your build sbt? Perhaps you didn't define your log library.

Comment: I haven't done anything about logging, except adding `scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"`, as the error message suggested. I don't have experience with Play and SBT but intuitively, shouldn't a project work if its logging is not configured?(I am not calling `Logger` anywhere)

Comment: I think your problem could be in your `routes` file. Did you add an entry in that file for `Application.addPerson()`?

Comment: Yes, I have. `POST    /person                     controllers.Application.addPerson`

Comment: It can still be something simple to solve. Can you update your question with the `addPerson` function?

Comment: Also, how does your `plugins.sbt` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a problem with sorm version. Maybe the version 0.3.8 (which is very old, from 2013) was not properly released for version 2.11 of scala.

Update sorm to the following version:

```
"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19"
```

For a reference, see this issue which was fixed a long time ago too:

https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/34